# Getting value of cell from a row where values between two other columns match

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA for Excel and am looking for some guidance.  I am trying to get the VBA code to do the following:
When a value for the Predecessor (column G) is changed the VBA looks for the same value in the ID column (Column A). It then needs
to change the value of Start Date (column D) on the line where the predecessor value was changed to equal the value of the End Date (plus one day)
of the line where the ID's value was located.
For instance, on the screenshot, I added a predecessor of "1" to Task Three.  The VBA should make the value of the Start Date for Task Three equal
the End Date of Task One (plus one day) where the ID of Task One equals the Predecessor of Task Three.
[image]

Comment: I wonder whether you even need VBA for this...

Comment: I need to be able to populate column D manually when no predecessor (col G) is set.  Using formulas is a problem because when values are entered manually it deletes the formula and editing the spreadsheet makes the automation stop working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, copy the next event code in the sheet code module where the range you show exists:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 7 Then
    Dim arr: arr = Me.Range("A2:G" & Me.Range("A" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(i, 1) = Target.Value Then
             If arr(i, 5) <> "" Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                 Target.Offset(, -3).Value = arr(i, 5) + 1
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
   End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to make this code run if I change the value in columns D or F?  Right now it runs when column G changes.  This way if I change the duration (col F) or start date (col D) it will automatically correct the start date of the successors.

Comment: @Brent I'm afraid, I cannot get you... **What** to be changed and **based on what**? I mean where the code algorithm to search/check and do what... Anyhow, I cannot understand the relation between Duration and the two dates. In the first filled row, it looks to be 10, if a formula (or something else) calculates the difference between the two dates...